# Google can't crawl site because of a 301

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

**Problem:**

Like a total noob i did a 301 redirect instead of a 302. Now Google is on the struggle bus trying to find the new website. I went from a HTML website to a WordPress website. I did a 301 redirect on http://www.themurraypestcontrol.com/index.html to http://www.themurraypestcontrol.com/v1/index.html, while i was building the new website. Apparently "permanent" didn't register in my mind. I am now trying to get Google to crawl https://themurraypestcontrol.com, but the 301 appears to be affecting my ability to create an accurate sitemap. I believe this is one of the reason Google can't crawl my site properly.

**Goal:**

- Fix URL so that Google can find the website and crawl. Organically the website has fallen off a cliff. I have tried every trick I know in Goggle Webmaster tools, but I can't get the new website to show up in search results.
- Enable HTTPS on the new URL
- Preferrably have https://www.themurraypestcontrol.com as the main URL

**Potential Solutions:**

- Forward https://themurraypestcontrol.com to https://www.themurraypestcontrol.com
- Forward
  http://www.themurraypestcontrol.com to
  https://www.themurraypestcontrol.com
- Move the website up one
  directory to https://www.themurraypestcontrol.com/v1, then 301 redirect all traffic

**What i know:**

This website, http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php, confirms that the redirect happened.

[image]

While trying to generate a sitemap, i see this (see screenshot). So the 301 redirect was not on the https URL it was on the http URL. 
[image]

When i put in https://themurraypestcontrol.com it generates this sitemap ([LINK](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aty0toPNNjK9jYQ-6eQZ8rsLUehogw)). This sitemap does not include the main pages of the website.

```
themurraypestcontrol.com/general-pest
themurraypestcontrol.com/termites
themurraypestcontrol.com/bed-bugs
themurraypestcontrol.com/contact-us
```

**robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://themurraypestcontrol.com/sitemap.xml
```

**.htaccess**

The .htaccess has a lot of stuff i have never seen, but I know it is possible to do a 301 or 302 from the .htaccess.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 6 hours"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 10 minutes"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 3 hours"
</IfModule>
Header set X-Endurance-Cache-Level "2"
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF
```

Comment: when you did the 301 redirect? bcz google will take time to crawl, and you need to add one more time like https://themurraypestcontrol.com under webmaster tools

Comment: @charankumar it has been a few weeks now.

Comment: @charankumar how can google crawl if the sitemap is messed up?